# RN-42 Bluetooth - Can't use data mode with Tera Term

Tags: bluetooth

I just got the RN-42, and I am using a simple set-up where I just power the chip, and short-circuit the UART Rx and Tx pins, hoping that whatever I send from my "Tera Term" terminal will be returned back to me. But no..

The thing is that I can enter 'Command Mode', so I am certain that I can connect to the module, but then, when I exit Command mode (and presumably enter Data mode), I type characters in and nothing gets returned.

Furthermore, I tried opening a second terminal window, for the other port created by the bluetooth connection, but still, no data going back or forth (even though I am certain that by short-circuiting the Tx and Rx Pins, data should be displayed on the first terminal).

Oh yeah, and I also tied together the CTS and RTS pins just in case, but still, no results.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Here are the module's settings as retrieved using the D, E, and O commands:

```
***Settings***
BTA=000666639EDE
BTName=RNBT-9EDE
Baudrt(SW4)=115K
Mode  =Slav
Authen=1
PinCod=1234
Bonded=0
Rem=NONE SET
***ADVANCED Settings***
SrvName= SPP
SrvClass=0000
DevClass=1F00
InqWindw=0100
PagWindw=0100
CfgTimer=255
StatuStr=NULL
HidFlags=200
DTRtimer=8
KeySwapr=0
***OTHER Settings***
Profile= SPP
CfgChar= $
SniffEna=0
LowPower=0
TX Power=0
IOPorts= 0
IOValues=0
Sleeptmr=0
DebugMod=0
RoleSwch=0
Ver 6.15 04/26/2013
(c) Roving Networks
```

Comment: Can you try to follow the ["Bluetooth lab manual"](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Bluetooth%20lab%20manual_bt_r.pdf) from Microchip? In Part 2, iw shows how to verify that a serial connection via the RN-42 works.

Comment: Thanks, but I did all that and I still can't send data across.

Comment: My question was more like: do the examples from the lab manual work for you or not?

Comment: Well, I can discover the module from a PC and establish a connection with it like described in "part 2", but I can not send data back and forth.. Keep in mind that I can not replicate microchip's instructions, as I don't have the evaluation kit - only the module

Comment: @DimC could you please share your solution with us if you have solved it? I am having the same difficulty. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps changing the baudrate to 9600 help you. 
I saw this problem and finally find out tera term don't show characters.